# What am I doing wrong with the definition of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are sets $$P(A)\cup P(B)\subset P(A\cup B)$$
$\Leftrightarrow$
Which seems easy using definitions:

Let $$a\in P(A)\cup P(B) \Leftrightarrow (a\in P(A)) \lor (a\in P(B))$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (a\subset A) \lor (a\subset B)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a\subset A\cup  B$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a\in P(A\cup B)$$

This would mean $$P(A)\cup P(B)= P(A\cup B)$$
It seems theres a wrong "$\Leftrightarrow$". Can't find it :/

Comment: tldr: your second $\Leftrightarrow$ should only be a $\Rightarrow$.  Specifically, $a\subseteq A\cup B$ does not imply that $a\subseteq A$ or $a\subseteq B$.  For example, when $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$ you have that $\{1,2\}\subseteq A\cup B$ however $\{1,2\}$ is neither a subset of $A$ nor is it a subset of $B$.

Comment: Oh!, so $a$ could be $A\cup B$ itself, meaning it isn't a subset of any of $A$ or $B$. This makes me wonder if i have to be more rigurous about the diference of $\subset$ and $\subseteq$?

Comment: Many authors unfortunately use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ interchangeably to mean the same thing.  I was originally taught that $\subset$ meant proper subset, but then had to get out of that habit as the next professor I had never used the symbol that way.  If you want to be absolutely clear that you intend to use a symbol to denote a *proper subset* (one which is a subset but not equal) then $\subsetneq$ is unambiguous.

Comment: If you could post this as an answer i'd give you credit, thank you a lot.

Comment: Eh... Hagen's answer is essentially identical to my own.  Give it to him instead.  I stopped caring about points a while ago (*which might explain why I've gotten in the bad habit of answering in comments section on occasion*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The penultimate one. $a\subset A\cup B$ does not imply $(a\subset A) \lor (a\subset B)$. For example, consider $a=\{1,3\}$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4\}$.